# Linux: Can a function be used as the source for a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to simulate a folder that can be presented to via vsftp where the contents of the folder are based on:

```
find /mnt/LargeDataFiles -name 2015_*.zip
```

Such that a user would log in and only see the files from the source directory that meet the pattern.

I would like to avoid using a cron job to copy the files into a user directory.   Two copies of the same file are never good.

```
find /mnt/LargeDataFiles -name 2015_*.zip -exec cp -Rup {} /home/user/large
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `ln -s /orig/path/file /new/path/file` as a script that is invoked like `find /dir -name X* | xargs fileSoftLinkerScript` ? Good luck.

Comment: You could use hardlinks with the cron job.

Comment: A fuse filesystem might also work here but a link tree (symlink or hard link) is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about using hard links ? Hard links are not copies - they are just another view(s) of the same content on disk, just under different name and (possibly) location. It seems like this is what you want.